# how use parse data into another controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, parsing, codeigniter-3

am now workng with  codeigniter  parse . am try to make template .because every controller/view have same menu..  it load from database.so have lot of database hit . am try to look session but it menu dynamic data it have lot of data so check parse [check here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html?highlight=parse)  am try to take data from database it work fine but how can i send that pasre data into another controller.

> how can i reuse once take  data from database . without hit database.
>    in effectivy way 
>   https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer below URL it will help you.
http://www.innovativephp.com/introduction-to-templating-and-dynamic-views-with-codeigniter/
I created template in codeigniter same like you want by using this article and hope help you too.

Comment: thank you @ ravi shankar. am using code am give below

Comment: public function hellodb()
        {
             $this->load->database();
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT cust_id,name,ml_name FROM mc_customers");

            $this->load->library('parser');

                $data = array(
                        'blog_title'   => 'My Blog Title',
                        'blog_heading' => 'My NIC Wayanad',
                        'blog_entries' => $query->result_array()
                );

            $this->parser->parse('home', $data);
        }

Comment: am using ref  https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html?highlight=parse#CI_Parser::parse  this is work perfect on one control how can i send that parse value into another controller

Comment: You have to include the  library ($this->load->library('parser');) on that controller too in order to work , best option is add this library in auto load so you don't need to upload the library on every controller and also create  header/footer file and include direct in template file.

Comment: is it possible to transfer parse data not parse library ... am create one parse controller that value display on that view . that working okey but how can i show this same parse data value on another view.... "because this data come from database. if am call this function it going to hit datbase again. "

Comment: Yes, but for that you have to use session or flash message to send data another controller, you can't send direct that data to another controller.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.shankar . that is my requirement .. i want to  store some large amount of data from database .so which one i prefer session or flash message ... will  u plz tell me any refer site on flash message in codeigniter

Comment: I would like to go with session :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface and implement it on the controller....

```
interface Example {
//code here
}

class YourController extends CI_Controller implements Example{
//Use what you want
}
```